# Is there a `loadedmetadata` for html5 img?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm rendering large images which are streamed natively by the browser.

What I need is a Javascript event that indicates that the image's dimensions were retrieved from its metadata. The only event that seems to be firing is the `onload` event, but this is not useful as the dimensions were known long before that. I've tried loadstart but it does not fire for img elements.

Is there a [loadedmetadata](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/media.html#event-media-loadedmetadata) event for the `img` element in html5?

Comment: HTMLImageElement does not inherit from HTMLMediaElement; so, I wouldn't expect access to media events.

Comment: @canon where do you find a complete list of HTMLImageElement events? I've tried https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-img-element.html#the-img-element but no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is not an equivalent of `loadedmetadata` for `img` elements.

The most updated specs at the time of writting are the [w3 Recommendation (5.2)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/) (or the [w3 WD (5.3)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html53/)) and the [WHATWG Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/). Although I find easier to browse through all the [events in MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events); their docs are more user friendly.

You can check that `loadedmetadata` is the only event related to metadata and that it applies just to HTMLMediaElements.

You could take advantage of the [Streams API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API) to access the streams of data, process them and extract the metadata yourself. It has two caveats, though: it is an experimental technology with limited support and you will need to look for a way to read the image dimensions from the data stream depending on the image format.

I put together an example for PNG images based on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams#Reading_the_stream).

Following the [PNG spec](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html), the dimensions of a PNG image are just after the signature, at the beginning of the IHDR chunk (i.e., width at bytes 16-19, height at 20-23). Although it is not guaranteed, you can bet that the metadata of every image format is available in the first chunk that you receive.

```js
const image = document.getElementById('img');

// Fetch the original image
fetch('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/de/Wikipedia_Logo_1.0.png')
  // Retrieve its body as ReadableStream
  .then(response => {
    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    return stream = new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        let firstChunkReceived = false;
        return pump();

        function pump() {
          return reader.read().then(({
            done,
            value
          }) => {
            // When no more data needs to be consumed, close the stream
            if (done) {
              controller.close();
              return;
            }
            // Log the chunk of data in console
            console.log('data chunk: [' + value + ']');
            // Retrieve the metadata from the first chunk
            if (!firstChunkReceived) {
              firstChunkReceived = true;
              let width = (new DataView(value.buffer, 16, 20)).getInt32();
              let height = (new DataView(value.buffer, 20, 24)).getInt32();
              console.log('width: ' + width + '; height: ' + height);
            }
            // Enqueue the next data chunk into our target stream
            controller.enqueue(value);
            return pump();
          });
        }
      }
    })
  }).then(stream => new Response(stream))
  .then(response => response.blob())
  .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
  .then(url => console.log(image.src = url))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

```html
<img id="img" src="" alt="Image preview...">
```

**Disclaimer**: when I read this question I knew that the Streams API could be used but I've never been in a need to extract metadata so I've never made ANY research about it. It could be that there are other APIs or libraries that do a better job, more straightforward and with wider browser support.