How to detect the "first render" of a progressively loaded image in JavaScript?
Some file formats like jpeg and webp allow "progressive loading" where the file is encoded in a way such that a lower resolution version of the image can be rendered before the entire file has finished loading.
However, the "onload" event will still only trigger once the image has fully loaded in its highest resolution state which begs the question of what to do if you are interested in the moment the image appear on the screen instead.
My question is if I can detect when the first lower resolution version has loaded and can be rendered?
something like:
// Hypothetical event
image.onreadytorender = () => placeholder.hide() && image.show();  

My usecase is that I want to remove and replace a LQIP (low quality image placeholder) with the real image as soon as it has loaded enough to render its low resolution version instead of having to wait for the fully loaded version which is what onload would do.
// This would not leverage the advantages of progressive loading
image.onload = () => placeholder.hide() && image.show()

Typically, all tutorials I have found on loading images says to use JS and the onload event to replace the placeholder with the real image. However, this does not make any sense considering how modern file formats like webp and avif work. One of their greatest advantages is that they can be rendered before it is fully loaded and onload is triggered. So is there a way to detect when the first paint of the image can happen? Or how do I leverage the advantages of progressive loading while also using a LQIP?
I have considered just loading the image on top of the LQIP without any JS, however, this would not work for images with transparency because the LQIP would be blurred causing it to overflow beneath the full image if it is not removed. It also would not trigger any fade in animations.

Check the answer for this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794923/is-there-a-loadedmetadata-for-html5-img
You can potentially do the same by monitoring the first chunks of image data and hiding placeholders at a certain point when it is clear that the image is ready to be rendered.

@RAllen Interesting solution, however, from my limited understanding, it would be very tedious / possibly impossible as you would have to build a full image parser for each file format and then find a way to get the browser to display this partial data as an image. I dont think it is possible as all image tools developers have access to expect a full image as input as far as I am concerned.

Well, your task is quite unusual, and hence, there is no straightforward solution for it. Even the browser doesn't have an API to address this specific scenario. This indicates that this is not a common thing that many people need. If you still think that this task is worth the extra effort, you will have to dig into complex and non-trivial solutions such as custom image parser. If the browser doesn't provide any means to detect stages of progressive loading, you have no other option but to detect them yourself or just forget about this advanced image loading feature and move on.

Look into this project https://github.com/jpeg-js/jpeg-js/blob/master/lib/decoder.js
It seems very lightweight - it has only 1145 in the decoder! It also has some handling for progressive images. It could be a good start if you feel adventurous.

Giving it a fixed height and width of the expected image while displaying a loading gif and then replacing with the images as they load completely work instead of the problems with LQIP. This way you also prevent a layout shift, keeping your CLS score down.

Could you give an example? Maybe I misunderstood you, but I dont see how this solves the problem of detecting when to remove the LQIP (or gif in your case) and replace it with the image.
